# WSO2 EI Registry(/_system/config/repository) values to be accessesd in proxy-service parameters

Tags: proxy, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Defined a proxy-service and need to access service parameters from registry. The below syntax is not working.

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">"conf:/repository/FileLocation"</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">"conf:/repository/FileMoveAfterFailure"</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">"conf:/repository/FilePattern"</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">"conf:/repository/FileMoveAfterProcess"</parameter>
```

How to access registry values under `/_system/config/repository` to use in proxy service parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot, the only option is to create a "file" inbound endpoint

```
<inboundEndpoint name="test_Inbound" protocol="file" sequence="test_Process" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="interval">5000</parameter>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.LockReleaseSameNode">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.AutoLockRelease">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter key="conf:/repository/FileLocation" name="transport.vfs.FileURI"/>
        <parameter key="conf:/repository/FileMoveAfterFailure" name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure"/>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.DistributedLock">false</parameter>
        <parameter key="conf:/repository/FilePattern" name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern"/>
        <parameter key="conf:/repository/FileMoveAfterProcess" name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess"/>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.CreateFolder">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Build">false</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

Then you have to do your processing in a sequence (test_Process), and of course adapt to your parameters (ContentType, interval, sequential or not....)

I never tried for transport.vfs.FileNamePattern but for the other I'm sure it's working as I'm using it.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. proxy-service did not support the registry name-key access, I found.